# problema carga de archivos en java jsf

Tags: jsf

Buenas tarde alguen me podria ayudar con este tema, la verdad hasta el momento no e encontrado buen material para estudiar, en internet hay varios videos pero ala mayoria son de jsp y actualmente uso jsf, tengo un trabajo de carga de archivos en donde me piden que haga la carga de estos en pdf y que la carga sea masiva, epero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bien podrias usar el componente para JSF, que es primefaces, y su p:fileupload, con opcion multiple. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                  multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

Y

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.file;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

Corriendo PrimeFaces-6.2.10 en Mojarra-2.3.2.

Aunque creo que no cambia mucho, pero siempre revisar.

Gracias a J. Castro por la revision, tiene razon en cuanto al enlace.

Saludos